# Import a class with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Given dot-notation of a python class, how would I import it if it's given as a string?

For example:

```
>>> from ingest.models import ItemInstance
>>> ItemInstance
<class 'ingest.models.ItemInstance'>
```

Given the string, `'ingest.models.ItemInstance'`, how would I import that?

---

**Note**: the above referenced duplicated is primarily about importing a module. Here I'm looking to specifically import a class. For example:

```
s = "ingest.models.ItemInstance"
cls = s.split('.')[-1] # works with the given path, but not always
module = '.'.join(s.split('.')[:-1])
getattr(importlib.import_module(module), cls)
```

The answer provided below addresses this accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.7 and Python 3.1 or later, you can use importlib:

```
import importlib

i = importlib.import_module("module_name")
```

If you want to access the class, you can use `getattr`:

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module("module_name")
class_ = getattr(module, class_name)
instance = class_()
```

Comment: Note, this will import the *module* (here 'ingest.models') but not the whole string including the class ItemInstance.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is there a way to get the actual class? The answer in the duplicate question also seem to talk primarily about importing modules/files.

Comment: Is my edited answer what you want?

Comment: @Marceline perfect, yes, exactly what I was looking for (not what the duplicate of just importing the module does). Thank you!